# Create Python's collections.counter() method in Beginner Racket

Tags: racket

The goal is to create a function that accepts a list of symbols and produces a list of key value pairs that count how many times each symbol in list appears. eg:

`(counter (list 't 't 'c 'a)) -> (list (list 't 2) (list 'c 1) (list 'a 1))`

**The function must be completed with recursion**

I've only gotten as far as to create a list of key value pairs that treat duplicates as standalone values:

```
(define val 0)

(define (counter los)
  (cond
    [(empty? los) empty]
    [else (cons (list (first los) (add1 val))
                (counter (rest los)))]))
```

`(counter (list 't 't 'c 'a)) -> (list (list 't) (list 't) (list 'c 1) (list 'a 1))`

Comment: Are you referring to the `beginner student language` ?

Comment: @sinanspd yes, beginning student with list abbreviations in particular

Comment: @adabsurdum apologies, the input is Symbols!

Comment: @trinity -- Thanks for responding; I edited your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a very long time since I used BSL but I believe these operations are all present. There may be a cleaner way of doing this but I will leave it up to you to check the documentation and simplify it if possible

```
(define (counter los) (counter-helper los empty))
(define (counter-helper los lists)
  (cond
    [(empty? los) lists] 
    [else (if (list? (assq (first los) lists))
                (counter-helper
                 (rest los)
                 (cons (list (first los) (add1 (second (assq (first los) lists))))
                      (remove (assq (first los) lists) lists)))
                (counter-helper (rest los) (cons (list (first los) 1) lists)))]))
```

the `if` statement checks if there is already an entry in our list of lists for that key, it returns the pair if yes, `false` otherwise.

If the result is `false` we just append a new pair with value 1 and recur.

If it already exists, we construct a new pair from the previous one, with the same key, but the value incremented and append this new pair to our list of lists - the previous pair removed

Comment: Just confirmed this does in fact work in BSL